# View Constructor with Dependency Injection throws NPE

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Yesterday I pushed my new Vaadin 13 Spring application to my server. When I then opened my app in the browser, the login and the dashboard view worked fine, but whenever I tried to navigate to a View that has a constructor with injected dependencies, it threw a NullPointerException. This never happens to me when I run the app locally!

I am at a total loss here and have no idea how to fix this. I have tried all possible variations how to annotate the injections for the view constructor. They all work when I run it locally, they all don't work on my server.
- annotate the whole constructor with `@Inject` or `@Autowired`
- annotate every injected spring component parameter with `@Autowired`
- No annotation at all on the constructor

Here are the exception message and the stack trace:

> Error creating bean with name 'path.to.ViewWithInjection': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [path.to.ViewWithInjection]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:304)
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:88)
com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:158)
com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:116)
com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer$$Lambda$732.000000007C0ED790.get(Unknown Source)
java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:115)
com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:167)
com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:221)
com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:192)
com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.lambda$initializeUI$caa7783a$1(Router.java:93)
com.vaadin.flow.router.Router$$Lambda$717.000000007C0AEE30.onHistoryStateChange(Unknown Source)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.NavigationRpcHandler.handle(NavigationRpcHandler.java:66)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:379)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$0(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler$$Lambda$994.00000000A093B760.accept(Unknown Source)
java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:368)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:310)
com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545)
com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:227)
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:65)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:996)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1410)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:171)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:996)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:927)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1023)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:232)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using cloudfoundry (`cf-maven-plugin:1.1.3`) to push to my IBM Cloud, and liberty (`liberty-maven-plugin:2.4`) to run locally.
My Vaadin Version is `13.0.0.beta3` but with `12.0.7` the same happens. This is the first time I wanted to run a Vaadin Flow application on a server so I'm *not* saying that this caused by a new minor version raise.
Springframework version in use is `5.1.2.RELEASE`

How can I make dependency injection work in my view constructors, when the app runs on the server?

Comment: Can you please share the code where the NPE occurs?

Comment: In the whole stacktrace, there is not a single code mentioned that is from my project. I am still investigating this issue, and I have since come to the conclusion that this has nothing to do with vaadin and everything to do with our deployment of the app on IBM Cloud. I can't exactly point out the error yet, but as soon as I can I will update here.

Comment: There is one mention, `Failed to instantiate [path.to.ViewWithInjection]` so maybe there is something else than your dependency that is causing it, such as an environmental variable missing, some property not included in the config file, etc, hence my request to actually see what the constructor is doing...

Comment: The constructor could be empty and still throw that error, as long as there are injected components as parameters. The "Failed to instantiate [..]" is thrown in [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java#L304). No line of code in my constructor is executed so I see no reason to include it here

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird since it says that _"Constructor threw exception"_. Any chance you're somehow/accidentaly using an older version of your class? Can you do a debug and investigate the call stack?

Comment: the "Constructor threw exception" part comes from [BeanUtils.instatiateClass(ctor, args)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.java#L184)
I havent debugged it because I wouldn't know where to set the breakpoint. I just followed the code I linked to in my last comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189535/discussion-between-morfic-and-cashbee).

Comment: @Morfic I was wrong. The NPE indeed occurred within my constructor. The dependency injection worked just fine!

Comment: Called it :-) This is why I was insisting on seeing the code. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error was not caused by the Dependency Injection at all. The NPE was caused by a strange Locale that was set by the server. I used `UI.getCurrent().getLocale()` to get the locale, and apparently that locale was en-US although my server is in Germany and my browser is set to ch-DE. Since I do not have a resource bundle for en-US it threw a NPE.

After I checked better if the given Locale is supported, I can set the UI Locale to a default Locale (defined by me) if it is not supported by my bundles.