# Error creating bean with name 'graphQlUtility' defined in URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, openshift

My Application runs fine locally but when I deploy it to cloudservice, I am getting this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/profile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT- Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate.

Could someone help me to figure out what is causing this error.

Comment: There should be more information in the stack trace (under the `Failed to instantiate`). That information may point you to the problem. Or you can post it here and someone else can point you in the right direction :-)

Comment: More information is provided here.Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE] .

Comment: Can you post the *whole* stack trace in the original post? And is there any of your code that appears in the stack trace? Or is everything from Spring?

Comment: Perhaps this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940800/view-constructor-with-dependency-injection-throws-npe

Comment: For next time, try googling the error or class that's causing the problem, i.e. "AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory npe" :-)